# Hide rows in Excel if a cell contains a certain string value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hide the entire rows 8 to 32 in my worksheet if cell K22 contains "true" and if not I want them to be shown.

If anyone could help that would be great!

Heres what I've tried.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("K22").Value = "True" Then
    Rows("8:32").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Rows("8:32").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Dont you need to just flip False and True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Rows("8:32").EntireRow.Hidden = IIf(UCase(Range("K22")) = "TRUE", True, False)
End Sub
```